# Every $R$-module $M$ contains an indecomposable submodule.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

A module $M$ is indecomposable if it is non-zero and cannot be written as a direct sum of two non-zero submodules.
It is clear that every simple module is indecomposable. The converse is not true in general.

Do we can show that every $R$-module $M$ contains an indecomposable submodule?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is $R$ commutative? Are these all the assumptions you have?

Comment: $R$ need not be commutative

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not necessarily true.

Take a domain $R$ that is not right Ore, so that it has infinite right uniform dimension.

Let $T$ be any nonzero right ideal of $R$. The thing is that if you take any nonzero $x\in T$, then $xR$ is a copy of $R$ inside $T$. Since $R_R$ has infinite uniform dimension, then $T$ has to have infinite uniform dimension.

So, $R_R$ contains no nonzero indecomposable submodule. (An indecomposable submodule has uniform dimension $1$, but containing a copy of a module with infinite uniform dimension rules this out.)

So $R$ does not contain any nonzero indecomposable submodules.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is the statement true if $R$ is a ring such that every right $R$-module is simple or decomposable module?

Comment: A ring with this property need not be semisimple ring, since from theorem(2.7) in the paper "semiartinian v-rings and semiartinian von neumann regular rings" , $R$ is right semiartinian v-ring iff every $R$-module $M$ contains an injective submodule. Thus if $R$ is a semiartinian v-ring then every  $R$-module is simple or decompasabl module.

Comment: @rschwieb A decomposable module needn't be a direct sum of indecomposables.

Comment: @Mf.math Yes, you're right. A 2:00 am mistake :) I am not sure if the conclusion holds in that case.

Comment: @egreg yup ${}{}{}$

Comment: @rschwieb I think we can show that if $R$ is a ring such that every $R$-module is simple or decompasable module then every $R$-module contains an indecomposable submodule as follows: if M is simple then it is indecomposable, if M is decompasable module then by zorn's lemma M contains a maximal direct summand submodule, so it's complem must be simple submodule which is indecomposable.

Comment: @Mf.math Having trouble seeing why Zorn's lemma would apply to direct summands. Why would the union of a chain of summands be a summand? Granted that, I can see that the complement of a maximal summand would indeed be simple by an easy argument.

Comment: For example, in $\prod_{i=1}^\infty F$, $\oplus_{i=1}^\infty F$ is the union of a chain of summands, but the union is not a summand (it is an essential ideal). Of course, I think this ring is not semiartinian. Maybe there is something about that which addresses my concern?

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you very much. Would you suggest me books on rings and modules Can be useful in my studies.

Comment: @Mf.math what have you read already?

Comment: @rschwieb I have read some topics of two books, the first one is modules and rings by F. Kasch and the other is algebras, Rings and Modules Volume 1 by M. Hazewinkel

Comment: @Mf.math I can always recommend First Course in Noncommutative Rings and Lectures on Modules and Rings by T.Y. Lam. And Commutative Rings by Kaplansky.

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you very much.